# Creating a conditional drop-down menu in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of conditional drop-down menus, where typing in an option from A1 will generate a dropdown menu in B1 (there's a reason I don't have A1 as a dropdown).

Now, if there's only one option, I'd like that option to automatically fill. What I've been trying is an if->then style, where I can recognize in C1 if it's a single option or not based off of what's in A1. D1 can fill in the correct value as well.

I've gone into the data validation, and tried to play around with that to no luck. I've tried marges, but it's too much work. Does anyone know how to get conditional dropdown menus to work the way I'm trying to get them, or can point me in a direction to research?

Comment: please provide a sample of how you want things to work.  What you describe sounds along the lines of -  B1 can have a drop down, possibly with a blank value.  Then logic in c1 to figure out choice. Perhaps, if B1 is blank, then use logic, else use B1. The logic can come back with Xray or whatever the answer is, or "Use b1 to select, can not tell answer"

Comment: So, if A1 = Pizza, B1 will give me a dropdown menu with Dominos, Pizza Hut, and Little Ceasars. However, if A1 = Chinese, then B1 will automatically fill in Panda Express, no need for me to click on anything or deal with the dropdown menu at all.

It'd also be nice if I can just click into B1 and enter what I want without removing data validation first, but that might be too tricky. So I could click on B1 when A1 is pizza and overwrite the choices with a local joint.

Comment: Assume there are 2 lists, Pizza & Burger, you can have b1 display appropriate dropdowns depending on a1.  In c1, you can have logic that looks at b1 if choice in a1 is not clear cut.  I would make a1 a dropdown and use its logic for all the rest.  What part of this do you need help with?

Comment: Also, what version of excel are you using.

Comment: Going back to the Chinese example, I don't want a dropdown menu for Chinese. I want a certain value to autofill instead. So If A1=Pizza, then dropdown menu. If A1=Chinese, then "Value". What you're proposing is a few linked dropdowns, which isn't what I'm going for. 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turning off the warning lets me input whatever I want.

A1 is the cell I'm filling
B1 is the cell I'd like to update
C1 is the cell that's "validating" B1 (is there only one entry on the list or not)
D1 is pulling the single entry if there is one.

On the table backend where my lists are stored, I do a vlookup in C looking to see if there's anything in the 3rd column. (the first one is my A1 entry, the second one is my first result, 2nd is the 2nd result, etc.) If there's nothing there, 0, otherwise, 1.
D1 does the same vlookup, but looking at column 2, not column 1.

In B1 I put =IF(C1=0,D1,"") - If C1 says there's only one entry, pull D1's entry, otherwise, leave it blank.

I then put a normal data validation over the cell.

So if Pizza gets entered, C1 says "nope, there's more than one entry", which triggers through to make B1 blank. The dropdown menu appears over it, and you can select your favorite pizza place.

If Chinese gets entered, C1 says "unique!", it triggers through to create a value shown in B1. It still validates properly, since it's on the list B1 is pulling.

Turning off the forced validation in the 3rd tab of the data validation allowed me to enter whatever value I wanted, so if I wanted a local pizza joint, I could add it in.

Hope this helps someone else that goes looking to do the same thing!